# Error opening attachment in outlook

Tags: civimail, email, attachments

When I send mailing with an attachment, contacts with use outlook can't open the attachment and received a message like this

[image]

I have tried with pdf and doc.
When I download the attachment to my computer, the size of the file is 0 byte.

The problem is the same if I use outlook in the browser.

An idea to solve the problem?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Can you try sending gmail? to be sure the problem is on the sender side (civi) and not on the recipient one.

if the size is 0 byte, it might be that you have a limitation in PHP on how big files you upload/process can be. Is this a problem you have all the time or only with these files? are they big?

Comment: That's working with gmail adn does'nt working for contact with office365 email. Previously that's worked for all. The size of the file is 1Mb. The problem occurs since one week, previous we didn't have any problems.

Comment: I have send the same attachment from a test server and I don't have any problems to open the attachment in outlook.